# How to prove $\lim_{q\to 1}{\frac{x^{1-q}-1}{1-q}}=\log(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Well it is mentioned at the title: I would like to prove that:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{q\to1}\log_q(x)=\log(x)
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
\log_q(x)={\frac{x^{1-q}-1}{1-q}}
\end{equation}
So far I am able to prove that for its inverse $e_q^x$ it holds: $\lim_{q\to1}{e_q^x}=e^x$ but not for $\log_q(x)$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that we can write

$$\frac{x^{1 - q} - 1}{1 - q} = \int_1^x t^{-q} \, dt$$
Letting $q \to 1$ and using either monotone convergence or dominated convergence to interchange the limit and the integral, we have

$$\lim_{q \to 1} \int_1^x t^{-q} \, dt = \int_1^x t^{-1} \, dt = \ln x$$

Comment: Convergence does hold, it is true. I could not have foreseen this particular relation between the integral and $\log_q(x)$. Nice one!

Comment: @Mitscaype Thanks. A really strong hint is to notice the appearance of the exponent in the denominator (together with already knowing that $\log x$ can be defined via an integral).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. You may use the fact that, as $q \to a$,
$$
\frac{f(q)-f(a)}{q-a}\to f'(a) \tag1
$$ if $f$ is differentiable near $a$.

Then apply $(1)$ with $f(q)=x^{1-q}$, $a=1$, observing that $f'(1)=-\log x$.

Comment: But that would give me instead $\log(1/x)$ as a result right?

Comment: @Mitscaype Not really, since the denominator is $q-1$ in my hint, not $1-q$. Thus you get the right result. Thanks!

Comment: True that! My bad! Thank you too :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's write $\frac{x^{1-q}-1}{1-q}$ as $\frac{e^{(1-q) \log(x)}-1}{(1-q) \log(x)}\log(x)$. As $q \rightarrow 1$ we get $\frac{e^{(1-q) \log(x)}-1}{(1-q) \log(x)} \rightarrow 1$ so $\lim_{q \rightarrow 1} \frac{e^{(1-q) \log(x)}-1}{(1-q) \log(x)}\log(x) = \log(x)$

Comment: A nice answer too. Thank you for it :D